# Attempt to read property "name" on bool

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a problem with Laravel 8 and I'm not sure how to identify the error.

The following happens ..

In my controller it looks like this:

```
$var  =  model::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
print_r($var)
```

Print_r returns this to me here

```
App\Models\test Object ( 
    [table:protected] => tb_test 
    [timestamps] => 
    [connection:protected] => mysql 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id 
    [keyType:protected] => int 
    [incrementing] => 1 
    [with:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [perPage:protected] => 15 
    [exists] => 1 
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array ( 
            [id] => 48494980 
            [name] => TEST
    ) 
    [original:protected] => Array ( 
            [id] => 48494980 
            [name] => TEST 
    ) 
    [changes:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [casts:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [dates:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [observables:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [relations:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [touches:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [visible:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) 
    )
```

when I try to use foreach, it returns me **Attempt to read property “name” on bool**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using a foreach? `$var` is a single model, not a collection, so a foreach wouldn't be necessary

Comment: Did you try using the getter?

Comment: to debug results in laravel, you should use `dd()` not `print_r()` or `var_dump()` unless you're confident on what you're doing. Anyway, $var contain a single object instance, ou can't foreach on it. if you want to walk the attributes, use `toArray()`

Comment: Works using toArray()
thank's for your time, guys

Answer (score 1):

If you want to walk the attributes one at a time, use `toArray()`

```
$var  =  model::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
$arrayVar = $var->toArray();

foreach( $arrayVar as $name => value) {
    //....
}
```